# How to mock a byte array by using EasyMock and PowerMock

Tags: java, easymock, powermock

I tyied just like this:

```
byte[] mockByteArray = PowerMock.createMockAndExpectNew(byte[].class, 10);
```

But I got runtime exception: An object method could not be found! How to fix it?

[Edit]
I want to mock a `RandomAccessFile.read(byte[] buffer)`:

```
byte[] fileCutter(RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile, long position, int filePartSize) throws IOException{ 
     byte[] buffer = new byte[filePartSize];
     randomAccessFile.seek(position); 
     randomAccessFile.read(buffer);
     return buffer;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to mock a byte array? Why not simply create a normal byte array?

Comment: Because I want to mock a RandomAccessFile.read(byte[] buffer):`byte[] fileCutter(RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile, long position, int filePartSize) throws IOException{ 
  byte[] buffer = new byte[filePartSize];   randomAccessFile.seek(position); 
  randomAccessFile.read(buffer); 
  return buffer; }`

Comment: I'm a fresh man and I don't know how to edit the code correctly. Forgive me, :(

Answer (score 3):

If you want to test the `fileCutter` method, you don't need to mock a `byte` array. You have to mock `RandomAccessFile`. For instance, like this (sorry for small syntax errors, I can't check now):

```
RandomAccessFile raf = EasyMock.createMock(RandomAccessFile.class);
// replace the byte array by what you expect
byte[] expectedRead = new byte[] { (byte) 129, (byte) 130, (byte) 131};
EasyMock.expect(raf.seek(EasyMock.anyInt()).once();
EasyMock.expect(raf.read(expectedRead)).once();

// If you don't care about the content of the byte array, you can do:
// EasyMock.expect(raf.read((byte[]) EasyMock.anyObject())).once();

myObjToTest.fileCutter(raf, ..., ...);
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but failed. Because I need to create a byte array in the `fileCutter`just like `byte[] buffer = new byte[10];`that is not the same as `expectedRead`,so I got
unexpected calling exception. That's why I have to mock a byte array.

Comment: I have sovled the problem!Really I don't have to mock a byte array.Here's my new code:

 `EasyMock.expect(mockRandomAccessFile.read((byte[]) EasyMock.anyObject())).andReturn(3);`

 `(byte[])EasyMock.anyObject()` will help me to match any byte array
called in the `fileCutter` method. Now I have go through my test!
Thanks a lot for your help! :D

Comment: If your problem is resolved it would be good form to mark the answer as Accepted.